# Do TypeScript conditional types map differently than constrained generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I am having no luck understanding why the code below functions as it does:

```typescript
type MapOverString<T extends string> = { [K in T]: K };

type IfStringMapOverIt<T> = T extends string ? MapOverString<T> : never;

type ThisWorks = MapOverString<'a'>;
// { a: 'a' }

type ThisAlsoWorks = IfStringMapOverIt<'a'>;
// { a: 'a' }

type Union = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type ThisWorksToo = MapOverString<Union>;
// { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }

type ThisDoesnt = IfStringMapOverIt<Union>;
// MapOverString<'a'> | MapOverString<'b'> | MapOverString<'c'>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmA8gNwgJwMrDQSwHYDmAPACpQQAewEeAJgM5T3b4EB8UAvFAN5QDaAaSj4oJALoAuKMIC+AbgBQi0JCgBJAGZZcheElRp1wUh25lK1Oo2a6CUAPywEKdDtamo0vBENKV4NAkABY49ADqAPZoANaM3PqumCyERADkcGlsSgD0ObxQcNIZaVCyyqpBofQAggA29JFRsfEa2ikEiYbG6ZnZinkFRVAlZRWBUACqeDiReFwjmVAAPiMARqWraQDGaf6VYtXNcSSRkQtdbh1E07N4-YN8wyUANFBrxRtv28W7YwFqEJhAAikQg9DwwAWWncehc3RMtzmD3yl2Sdl6WRWzgMVwxaQ2HFWaNhxB2WSAA)

I must be missing something, because `MapOverString` and `IfStringMapOverIt` seem like they should function identically.

Ultimately, I am using string literals and generics to cascade through permutations of configuration types. For example, if you want `StringConfig<T>` configured with options `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`:

```typescript
type ConfigMap<T> = T extends number
  ? NumberConfig
  : T extends string
    ? StringConfig<T>
    : never

type MyConfig = ConfigMap<'a' | 'b' | 'c'> // so many sad faces
```

Could someone enlighten me? What's going on here?

Comment: That's really interesting. And the answer to the title seems to be (from your code): Yes, they do. It's actually kind of cool to have both options. Note the difference if the union has a non-string in it (`"a" | 42 | "b"`). I have no idea *why* or what the rules are, though. :-)

Comment: The logic behind it seems pretty logical, like if you have a type `type SeparateStrings<T> = T extends string ? T : never` and you use it like `SeparateStrings<'a' | 42 | 'b'>` and expect yo get `'a' | 'b'`, it's logical what it does: it iterates over union types instead of working with this union as a single type. So such behaviour seems reasonable, no idea though, how to make it do what you want it to do, that's really interesting :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an application of the distribution property of conditional types. A condition over naked type parameter, will trigger this behavior and `T extends string` satisfies this. You might also see `T extend T` or `T extends any` or `T extends unknown` used for this very reason, just to trigger distribution.

You can read more about distributive conditional types in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

You can disable distribution by using a condition over a tuple `[T] extends [string]`. The effect of this is similar to a regular condition, just since the type parameter is no longer naked distribution will be displayed.

```
type StringConfig<T extends string> = { [K in T]: K };
type NumberConfig ={}

type ConfigMap<T> = [T] extends [number]
  ? NumberConfig
  : [T] extends [string]
    ? StringConfig<T>
    : never

export type MyConfig = ConfigMap<'a' | 'b' | 'c'> // so many sad faces
let x:MyConfig = {
  a:'a',
  b:'b',
  c: 'c'
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitReturns=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwMIHtkDNGoB4AVKCAD2AmQBMBnKWhFVAPigF4oBvKAbQGkoKKEQC6ALiiCAvgG4AUKEhQAcgFcAtgCMI8LLnwcu0+YvDR9eVAFkAhmGJtOvMaQpU6fZJp3xR8qCgAflUfXUt8AKhJF1E3Shp6XkYkNH9AwJC4VIxsK0cowMlkCAA3XVNyMEx4YCglaGsQCNQOKBa7BwByWy6oAB8oLq0+wa6AYy62AHpphkwoDVtkEAZbaigcW3GIWnkAGwg6snEmlrauKNtxHq6AGiitG5GHwPHJCa75E3kgA)

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing, thank you! The examples cited in the docs helped clarified that design decision, too. Appreciate the work around, as well - worked perfectly for me :)